# Why old stable files were not removed using DTCS?

Tags: cassandra

I create a table using dtcs, and set 
compaction = {'max_sstable_age_days': '5', 'base_time_seconds': '3600', 'max_threshold': '32', 'timestamp_resolution': 'SECONDS', 'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy'}

and gc_grace_seonds = 1800. However I still see disk usage keeping growth, and I can still see sstables  files that were older than 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1) You never mention your cassandra version. DTCS is new and there are a few bugs that prevent old sstables from being properly removed in some versions

2) timestamp_resolution is almost certainly not seconds - most drivers use microseconds, some use milliseconds. Seconds is unlikely.

3) max_sstable_age_days is the time when sstables will not be compacted - the date they are dropped depends on the TTL you set on the data when you insert it, not on max_sstable_age_days.